# sql sorting using multiple columns and simultaneously

Tags: android, sql

Data Set

```
Col A    Col B
15       23
54       53
24       34
65       45
74       54
```

Desired output

```
Col A   Col B
15      null 
null    23
24      null 
null    34
null    45
null    53
null    54
54      null
65      null 
74      null
```

Basically , Col A from Table A and Col B from Table B 
 and I do Join and finally I need a output like above

Currently I am using buildUnionQuery()  in android to join the result , but I could join the table one after the another not simultaneously .

Comment: Your data model seems to be out of touch with your needs.  Your desired output suggests having two separate tables, not two columns in a table.

Comment: Could you please format the post using source code notation? I can't see what your data set actually look like.

Comment: Agree with @AleksG - what is it you're trying to do (in a larger sense)?  Looks like you're trying for form of `UNION`ed queries (as opposed to a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, given `54` isn't in the same row).  So what is it you're trying to accomplish?